# Printing the letters from A-Z using recursion in c#

Tags: c#, recursion

So here's what I have so for, I'm trying to print all the numbers from A-Z but it only prints Z, please help and thanks (using recursion)

```
using system;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace AtoZRecursion
{ 
    class Program
    {  
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        int number=65;
        getAplha(number);
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(getAplha(number)));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static int getAplha(int number=65)
    {
        if (number==90)
        {
            return Convert.ToChar(number);
        }
        return Convert.ToChar(getAplha(number + 1));
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Well you only have one `Console.WriteLine` and it isn't in the recursive method.

Comment: Please consider marking your question answered by one of the many great answers below.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `WriteLine` from `Main` and put it just at the start of `getAlpha`, so that every letter is printed, as there is a call for each letter.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the return type of your method and invoke it like `Console.WriteLine(getAplha(65));`

```
public static string getAplha(int number = 65)
{
    if (number == 90)
    {
        return "" + (char)number;
    }
    return (char)number + getAplha(number + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The WriteLine only happens once, when you "pop" back from the deepest recursion level.
You need to write from the getAlpha method.

Answer (score 0):

You are only logging the last value of the recursion in `Console.WriteLine`. Instead, wrap your WriteLine like this:

```
using system;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace AtoZRecursion
{ 
    class Program
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number=65;
            getAplha(number);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static int getAplha(int number=65)
        {
            if (number==90)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(number));
                return Convert.ToChar(number);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(number));
            return Convert.ToChar(getAplha(number + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need the `Console.WriteLine` inside of the recursive method

```
public static void getAplha(int number=65)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(number));
    if (number==90)
    {
        return;
    }

    getAplha(number + 1);
}
```

And then you don't need a return type.